# Can I summon an otherworldly creature with the Gate spell without knowing its true name?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

Can I summon an otherworldly creature with the *gate* spell without knowing its true name?

For example, say I cast *gate* and say Orcus's name. Assuming he didn't veto the *gate* opening, would this summon him? Or would I have to say his true name for this to work?

Comment: What makes you think that "Orcus" isn't Orcus's true name?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### You must know the target's actual name to summon them via *Gate* (but there's no indication that Orcus's name isn't really Orcus)

As the [*gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) spell describes:

> When you cast this spell, you can speak the name of a specific creature (a pseudonym, title, or nickname doesn't work).

The specific term "true name" isn't used here - perhaps deliberately, to avoid harkening back to the (awful) truenaming magic system from earlier editions. As long as the name is a name legitimately used as a sort of proper name by the entity you're trying to summon, you get that creature.

You can't cast *gate* and say:

- Mr. Sucro (this is a *pseudonym* Orcus uses when booking hotel reservations incognito)
- The Blood Lord (this is Orcus's *title*, not his name)
- Orcy-Worcy (this is your affectionate *nickname* for Orcus)

But you can say "Orcus", and get Orcus, assuming he deigns to allow the gate to open in the first place<sup>1</sup>. There's no indication in the manuals that I can find that Orcus's proper name is anything other than just Orcus.

1<sub>He's probably cool with you saying hi if you're on an "Orcy-Worcy" basis with him.</sub>

Comment: "Orcy-Worky" made me legitimately laugh out loud.

Comment: Not sure if any of this is correct, but a [reddit thread attempted to figure out if Orcus was the true name](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/7mh05x/orcuss_true_name/).

Comment: @guildsbounty Indeed they are, but that's not a "True Name" what gate asks for - just the plain old regular name.

Comment: @T.Sar Oh...huh....missed that somehow.

Comment: I'm with Rubiksmoose on that.

Comment: Mr. Sucro. I'm going to use that and see how long it takes my players to figure it out. I'm sure they'll spend way too long thinking "Sucro means Sugar. There must be some hidden meaning in that..." Though I have to wonder - if you summon Sucro, do you get mirror universe Orcus?

Comment: @cpcodes No, you get George Sucro. The shopkeep who owns the drygoods store down the street. Awkward.

Comment: @cpcodes You get the version of Orcus that gives expensive gifts to his followers in the form of nice cars, clothes, and very expensive jewelry. Sometimes even a few _Slippery Potions_ or a _Rod of Earthquakes_.